# Elasticsearch must_not bool query is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have a bool query with a `filter` and a `must_not` clause. But when I execute the query I get results that contain the values specified in the `must_not` clause. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

### Query

```
POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "partnerId": {
              "value": 12345
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "stage": {
              "value": "REJECTED"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true
    }
  }
}
```

### Response

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "45678910",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 45678910,
          "partnerId": 12345,
          "stage": "REJECTED"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Mappings

```
"mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "partnerId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "stage": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Notice how in my results I'm still getting a `REJECTED` stage even though I've included that in the `must_not` clause.

Elasticsearch version : 6.2.2

Comment: Could you include your mapping for this index?

I ask because this issue can sometimes happen if a field (e.g. "stage") uses an analyzer that does case-conversion. You could verify whether this is the issue by changing your "term" filters to "match" filters.

Comment: @JasonRosendale I think you just helped me figure it out. It looks like my 'stage' field is a text field and therefore I would have to reference the keyword value if I want to use the `term` filters. I switched it to use "match" filters like you suggested and it worked as expected :)

Comment: Either use a `match` query with the `stage` field or use the `stage.keyword` field with a `term` query

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with string, you should either :

- use match for the row string
- use term with the keyword from the string

You have everything you need on the official documentation

[Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-match-query.htm) and [Term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

To use match :

```
GET /_search
{
"query": {
    "match" : {
        "message" : "this is a test"
        }
    }
}
```

To use Term :

```
POST _search
{
"query": {
    "term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" } 
    }
}
```

I hope I helped you